# Constant expression required in switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement, constants

I have already initialized constant expressions for my string. What seems to be the problem here?

The error I am getting is "constant expression required".

Below is my code,

```
public class VatCalculator {

    private static int ONBOARD_SALE =1;
    private static int ONBOARD_SERVICE =2;
    private static int PREORDER_SALE =3;
    private static int PREORDER_SERVICE =4;

    private static final Map<String, Integer> serviceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    static {
        serviceMap.put("onboardSale", ONBOARD_SALE);
        serviceMap.put("onboardService", ONBOARD_SERVICE);
        serviceMap.put("preorderSale", PREORDER_SALE);
        serviceMap.put("preorderService", PREORDER_SERVICE);
    }



public static double calculate(String serviceGroup) {

int type = serviceMap.get(serviceGroup);

switch(type) {
//error at below line
case ONBOARD_SALE:
        //do something

default:break;
    }
}
```

Comment: (An enum would probably be nicer.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
private static final int ONBOARD_SALE = 1;
```

Comment: I used final initially and it works but I don't want to make it final. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Change the logic. You can't use variables in switch so you must either have finals or values, like "case 1". Maybe you could create enum and then use it. Btw. switch is not OOP so it would be better to find another logic.

Answer (score 0):

check brace

```
    public class VatCalculator {

        private static int ONBOARD_SALE =1;
        private static int ONBOARD_SERVICE =2;
        private static int PREORDER_SALE =3;
        private static int PREORDER_SERVICE =4;

        private static final Map<String, Integer> serviceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        static {
            serviceMap.put("onboardSale", ONBOARD_SALE);
            serviceMap.put("onboardService", ONBOARD_SERVICE);
            serviceMap.put("preorderSale", PREORDER_SALE);
            serviceMap.put("preorderService", PREORDER_SERVICE);
        }


    public static double calculate(String serviceGroup) {

        int type = serviceMap.get(serviceGroup);

        switch(type) {
            //error at below line
            case ONBOARD_SALE:
                    //do something

            default:break;
        }
    }
    } //<-- add like this brace
```

Comment: It's proper in my code.. I must have accidentally added the brace here. Will edit it.